# Javascript pass values to another funtion

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass the search value to another function. The search value is dynamic i.e user input. The search value is called from an api

here is the code
HTML

```
<html>

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body> 

<script src="app/d.php"></script>
<script src="app/d.js"></script>

<form id="searchform" onsubmit="searchform(this)">

<input id="searchterm" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search Directory">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><button id="all" onclick="searchAll(this)">All</button></li> 
    <li><button id="staff" onclick="searchAll(this)">Staff</button></li>
    <li><button id="faculty" onclick="searchAll(this)">Faculty</button></li>
   <li><button id="students"onclick="searchAll(this)">Students</button></li>
 </ul>
    <p id="demo">
        <br></p>
</body>

    <script>


    </script>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var fil="";
var search="";
function searchAll(filValue){
   fil=filValue.id;
}
function searchform(searchterm){
 search=($('#searchterm').val());
    search(search);
}
function search(search,fil){
$(document).ready(function(){
var query_json = {"search_string":search, "filter":fil};
    json_call(query_json); 
       });

function json_call (values) {

$.post("app/d.php", {values} ,function(response) {
var str = "";
for(var i in response.Contacts){
console.log(response.Contacts[i].displayName);
 str += response.Contacts[i].displayName;
        }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;

    }, 'json');
}



 php
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://olddominion.campusdish.com/api/service.svc/menu/locations",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json"),
                 ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}

?>
```

How can I pass the user selected search term value and filter value to the search function to call values from the API.